# Custom PPP chat script on pfsense

Tags: ppp

Hi have a Dell 3G modem installed on my Alix-6f based pfsense router / firewall. In order to connect to the Internet (Telstra) I perform the following in the console :

- ppp (enters the ppp interactive shell)
- set device /dev/cuaU1
- term (enters the term shell, whatever that is)
- AT+CFUN=1 (enables the modem, I think)
- AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","telstra.wap" (sets an access point)
- AT*ENAP=1,1 (enables the access point)

From that point on the link is up and I switch to another shell to assign an IP to the USB ethernet device (part of the 3G modem):

- dhclient ue0

**My question is how can I make pfsense automatically connect & reconnect on startup or on disconnect?** I have tried configuring a PPP connection using the webconfigurator GUI but I haven't managed to get it working. I also tried setting up ue0 using PPPOE however it is not an authenticated connection! It could be something to do with the relationship between /dev/cuaU1 and the ethernet device ue0?

I admit that I'm a n00b when it comes to ppp... ;)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Activate the SSH Shell on your pfSense box, the File you need to modify is /usr/local/sbin/mpd.script, it gets called by mpd on startup